# Crystal Reports Continuous page

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm wondering if it is possible to have a crystal report with no page breaks. I have a report that won't be printed. I need it to be one continuous page for however long it needs to be. I haven't been able to find any discussions regarding this on any forums

Answer (score 0):

Go to File, Page Setup... and either set the page size to the tallest option one of your printers supports or turn on the option to 'Dissociate Formatting Page Size and Printer Page Size' and then set the page size to whatever you need.